# what is the meaning of median of(first,middle and last) elements?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort

Can anyone tell me, what is the median for the above problem in Quick sort? Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort these values, median will be in the center of sorted list

If `a <= b <= c` then b is median of a,b,c

`12,5,8` - median is 8

Answer (score 1):

In QuickSort, median-of-three is one of the ways to choose a pivot in each iteration. The pivot is an element in the array, which is used for partitioning the array by comparing all of its values to the pivot.

The ideal pivot value is the median of the array, but this takes time to compute. So, people have been using the leftmost value of the array as a simple pivot value. But this is performs badly when the array is already sorted.

The median-of-three rule, recommended [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#cite_note-sedgewickBook-17), is one of the ways to get good performance in case of an already-sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are good, here is a (clearer) example:

```
{ 9, 7, 4, 12, 3, 1, 6, 1, 7, 4, 13, 2, 4, 15, 8, 9 }
```

Pick three values at random, three times:

```
{ 9, 7, 4 }
{ 2, 12, 15 }
{ 4, 1, 8 }
```

Find the median of each: 7, 12, 4.
Find the median of that: 7

Use this as your pivot.

Answer (score 0):

The median of the 3 numbers is the second largest number.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.